merge rows based on first column and concatenate all other columns with comma delimiter
df0:
              CC          AN
0             67562       EPC9999A
1             67562       EPC9999B
2             67994       EPXFXXXA
3             67995       EPXFXXXS

Desired Result:
              CC          AN
0             67562       EPC9999A, EPC9999B
1             67994       EPXFXXXA
2             67995       EPXFXXXS

Wondering how to do this in python possibly with pandas ?
I tried merge with pandas and couldn't get the Desired Result

df.groupby('CC', as_index=False).agg(', '.join)
